# Android: Html.fromHtml() handle non-standard html tags

Tags: android, html-parsing

I am parsing an html message which may contain user-defined tags, e.g. `<usertag uservalue="value" />`.

I am using standard Html.fromHtml() function to parse the html source. Unfortunately it simply ignores non-standard tags and remove these from the output. I would like to keep them.

I've tried to supply my own TagHandler to the fromHtml() function, but I do not know what to do inside the handleTag() function. Looks like I do not have access to the non-standard tag attributes\content from the TagHandler.handleTag() function? How do I use xmlReader passed inside fromHtml()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am parsing an html message which may contain user-defined tags, e.g. `<usertag uservalue="value" />`.

Then you do not have HTML.

Here are some options:

1. Get rid of the "user-defined tags" outright
2. Have your source markup be valid HTML, with your "user-defined tags" turned into valid HTML (e.g., using `<div>` and `<span>` with `class` attributes, as the microformats people do)
3. Pre-process your markup to handle your "user-defined tags", turning them into valid HTML, before calling `Html.fromHtml()`

Comment: Well, you can use `annotation` tag for customized handling of tags as I've shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50267693/878126 , but I don't know how to handle both the customized and the basic `Html.fromHtml` tags working together. Any idea?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: No clue, sorry.

Comment: Do you know perhaps of a good way to handle unsupported (meaning customized) tags for `Html.fromHtml` ? I've found some very weird workarounds, using reflection, which I think aren't worth using. This can help for example in the case of customized font tag.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Do you know perhaps of a good way to handle unsupported (meaning customized) tags for Html.fromHtml ? " -- no, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From what we can see in the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.TagHandler.html), there seems to be 4 parameters :

- opening, specifying if this is an opening or closing tab
- tag, presumably the tag name
- output, which is the generated Editable to which you'll add your data
- xmlReader, the current XML reader.

It looks like you can't use the attributes, though.

One last solution, although a little bit complicated, would be to reimplement `Html` to suit your needs. You can find its source [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/text/Html.java).

Comment: Exactly. I only need to get the tag text as-is with all attributes and put it in the output. However I only have access to tag name.

Comment: A last solution would be to redo Html yourself. Added some details about that.